# How to configure Microsoft exchange 2007 with evolution

Tags: evolution, ms-exchange

I got following error while collection

> The Exchange server is not compatible with Exchange Connector.
>
> The server is running Exchange 5.5. Exchange Connector  supports
>   Microsoft Exchange 2000 and 2003 only.

My server is hosted on ms exchange 2007

So is there any way out ?

Answer (score 2):

**EMAIL**: you should consider accessing with **IMAP** and **SMTP** protocols, if your server have them enabled. I was an happy Evolution user, but in the last months I had a lot of problems with it, and now I'm switching to Thunderbird, that finally is well integrated with Ubuntu, works well with IMAP and seems also faster.

**CONTACTS**: in Thunderbird, you can add the Exchange Global Address List as a Remote LDAP Address Book; the port 389 should be opened on Exchange server. In Evolution, I was not able to make this working.

**CALENDAR**: no way in Evolution. In Thunderbird, you can work with the Exchange calendar with [Lightning](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/?src=ss) extension and [Exchange 2007/2010 Calendar and Tasks Provider](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/exchange-20072010-calendar-/?src=hp-dl-upandcoming), that uses EWS (Exchange Web Services). I just tried and works very well!

*ALTERNATIVE*: you can also try [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/), what access to Exchange Web Services and act as a "proxy" for standard apps (IMAP, SMTP, LDAP, Caldav). But, I tried it some time, and I was not satisfied. Too many problems to solve...

Comment: +1 for recent problems with evolution... going to try to set up t-bird